# Shortcut syntax for doing var = var + n?

Tags: c#, post-increment, unary-operator

I'd like to increment my `var` value of `n`, using a similar structure of the post-increment solution like `var++`.

The post-increment is like this:

```
int var = 0;
var++; // var = var + 1
```

I'd like to increment `var` of `n`, with `n = 4` for example. What's the correct syntax ?

```
int var = 0;
var++4; // var = var + 4 but obviously not working;
```

Comment: Are you looking for `var += 4;`? (`var += n;` in general case)

Comment: you want to increment in steps of `4`? like 1, 5, 9, 13... ? Off topic: `var` is a key word. You really should not use it as a variable name

Comment: yes that's what I was looking for. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is actually a [Compound assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#compound-assignment)  with arithmetic operators

```
int a = 5;
a += 9;
Console.WriteLine(a);  // output: 14

a -= 4;
Console.WriteLine(a);  // output: 10

a *= 2;
Console.WriteLine(a);  // output: 20

a /= 4;
Console.WriteLine(a);  // output: 5

a %= 3;
Console.WriteLine(a);  // output: 2
```

Comment: I very often use `OR` and `AND` Compound assignement:
`bool hasError = false;`
`hasErrors |= CheckErrors();`